# Rename category of a categorical variable that's less than 0.5% of the mode count, Value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very large df, lots of rows and columns. I want to rename the category of the categorical variable as "other" if it's less than 0.5% of the count of the mode.

I know `df[colname].value_counts(normalize=True)`  gives me distribution of all categories. how do i extract the ones less than 0.5% of the mode, and how to rename it as other?

```
  apple
large 100
medium 50
small  3

desired output

  apple
large 100
medium 50
other  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and compre by less by [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) for mask same size like original column, so new values are set in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
m = df['apple'].map(df['apple'].value_counts(normalize=True).lt(0.005))
df['apple'] = df['apple'].mask(m, 'other')
```

For count:

```
s = df['apple'].value_counts()
print (s)
large     100
medium     50
other       3
Name: apple, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to find values whose frequency is smaller than 0.5%, by value_counts and index.
 Second, you need to make a dictionary whose keys are the index and the value is "others".
Third, use replace with the dictionary to change values to others.

Here is an example.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"apple":["large"] * 1000 + ["medium"] * 500 + ["small"] * 1})

cond = df['apple'].value_counts(normalize = True) < 0.005
others = cond[cond].index
others_dict = {k:"others" for k in others}

df['apple'] = df['apple'].replace(others_dict)
```